# Write .htaccess file to configure subfolder as documentroot

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have the following directory structure. `/var/www/html` is the DocumentRoot.

```
var
  www
    html
      demo
        css
           abc.css
        js
           abc.js
        index.html
```

How can I write an .htaccess file in the "demo" folder such that all resources in that folder think that "demo" is the documentRoot instead.

ex: `http://myserver.com/demo/css/abc.css` should work.

In the code of index.html, I just want to refer to the CSS files this way:

```
<link href="/css/abc.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

instead of `"/demo/css/abc.css"`

Comment: `How can I write an .htaccess file in the "demo" folder such that all resources in that folder think that "demo" is the documentRoot instead.` - You can't do that with a htaccess file; If it's static html it should use relative paths for assets, not absolute urls that point where file's aren't.

Comment: i have multiple sites like "demo" in the html folder.. I did setup alias parameter in the virtualhost to point to those folders.. They work. However, I am in fix specifying the paths for the CSS and JS resources

Comment: Do you want me to fix it such that css files point to css/abc.css instead of /css/abc.css

Comment: That's what I said - yes. Otherwise `http://example.com/demo1/index.html` requests `/css/abc.css`, `http://example.com/demo2/index.html` _also_ requests `/css/abc.css` and you have no way to rewrite the requests to where the files are.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Works for me.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/   #<---  Here.
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]       #<-- and here.
```

Comment: What is "folder" here?

Comment: The extra rules and using a foldername that isn't in the question doesn't help clarify your answer. I assume this is supposed to be in the html folder, and would break ~everything. You'd need something [more like this](https://gist.github.com/AD7six/2b642b62a2700539d82f) - but probably that'd work for only one demo at a time.

Comment: Word.  I was not very specific.